# sql Not exists query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i've the following sql query

```
declare @temp table(RevisionStatus varchar(100),DocTypeID varchar(50))
insert into @temp(RevisionStatus,DocTypeID)
select distinct md.RevisionStatus,dt.DocumentTypeID
from MissingDesignData md inner join tblDocumentType dt on md.[Doc Type]=dt.DocumentType inner join tblRevisionStatus rv on md.RevisionStatus=md.RevisionStatus

select distinct tm.RevisionStatus,tm.DocTypeID as 'DocType'
from @temp tm 
rv.RevisionStatus=tm.RevisionStatus and rv.DocType=tm.DocTypeID
where not exists (select distinct rss.RevisionStatus,rss.DocType from tblRevisionStatus rss)
```

i need to return the records where not exists in the tblRevisionStatus table but exists in @temp table.currently it return empty data set

when i select @temp data it's as follows

```
RevisionStatus  DocType
PEN - Pending   14
PEN - Pending   16
PEN - Pending   2
PEN - Pending   3
PEN - Pending   30
PEN - Pending   34
PEN - Pending   5
PEN - Pending   55
```

tblRevisionStatus data set return as

```
RevisionStatus              DocType

IFC - Issued For Construction       4
RFD - Revised As Denoted                4
IFU - Issued For Use            4
AB - As Built               NULL
C1 - Proceed, No Exception Taken            2
PEN - Pending               1
PEN - Pending               2
HLD - HOLD (Implementation Study ONLY)  1
```

when i run the above given sql query it returns nothing.but only

```
PEN - Pending       2
```

record exists in the tblRevisionStatus table so why the query does not return other records.am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the a list of rows that are in `@Temp` that are not in `tblRevisionStatus`, you can easily do this using the **EXCEPT** statement

```
select RevisionStatus, DocType
from @Temp

except

select RevisionStatus, DocType
from tblRevisionStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual method is to use primary Keys for this type of requirements but you can try following Code to Select results after transferring data into Temp Table

```
SELECT RevisionStatus,DocTypeID as 'DocType'
from @temp where RevisionStatus not in(select distinct RevisionStatus From tblRevisionStatus) and DocTypeID not in (select distinct DocTypeID From tblRevisionStatus)
```

I still stress on using primary Keys in all the tables

Comment: ohh.i corrected it but still the same result.no data in the final result set

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not using IN and DISTICTS. These are in most cases bad for the performance. So my suggestion is this:

```
SELECT 
    tbl.RevisionStatus,
    tbl.DocTypeID as 'DocType'
FROM 
    @temp AS tbl 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 
            NULL 
        FROM 
            tblRevisionStatus
        WHERE
            tblRevisionStatus.RevisionStatus=tbl.RevisionStatus
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 
                NULL 
            FROM 
                tblRevisionStatus
            WHERE
                tblRevisionStatus.DocTypeID=tbl.DocTypeID
        )
```